# InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "assetic" in config_dev.yml

Tags: symfony, bundle

i dont know how to fix this error.
here is my composer.jason :

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*@dev",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*dev",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web"
}
```

}

and here is my Appkernel.php :

```
 class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sdz\BlogBundle\SdzBlogBundle(),
        new Sdz\UserBundle\SdzUserBundle(),
        new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Ma\L4cBundle\MaL4cBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        //$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        //$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

}

i know that symfony bundle have inside assetics classes , so i think maybe there is a conflict with kriswallsmith asset.

Comment: and your `config_dev.yml`?

Comment: imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com